# How to create a term document matrix using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I think this is more general problem than I declared at topic.

I have three tables in db.

1. words (wordid, word) - 12136 rows
2. pages (pageid, page) - 1051 rows
3. pagewordindex (pagewordid, pageid, wordid, freq)

I want to create an html table to display word frequencies for each page.

```
|        |word1|word2|word3|....|wordn|
---------------------------------------
|page1   |   10|   12|    0|....|    1|
|page2   |    0|    1|    4|....|    2|
.......................................
|pagen   |    5|    4|    3|....|    9|
```

How can I use the words as column headers? What will be the SQL query?

Comment: You said you wanted to use html (which would be generated by PHP, as tagged), so (in mySQL) you don't need to use words as column headers at all. Just return a grouped, and ordered array. Also, note that pagewordid appears to be redundant

Comment: You want to have an html page with 1,502 columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it would be ok to have 10 rows X 10cols table.